# Weird asp.net MVC System.OutOfMemoryException :(

Tags: c#, .net, large-files

The program is deployed on IIS 8

Strange problem , if the application pool is recycled, the program will be normal for a short period of time, and the exception of memory overflow will be thrown later

I have thought of many solutions including code optimization for many versions, but have not been able to solve this problem, including writing using StringWriter, segment reading using BinaryReader, etc., can not solve this problem;

I used a SoapHelper class to access a webservice, and that webservice asked weirdly to upload attachments and messages to the interface together
So I read the relevant attachments in my own program and built Xml files to send them out;
When there are no attachments or small attachments, this method is fine, but if the attachments are too large, the memory overflow will be thrown ...
The requested Xml is 69M, as shown in the figure [xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTkQt.png)

This is trivial for a server with 56 logical processors with a usage rate of 1% and a memory usage of 64G with a usage rate of about 14%.

This is my exception message

```
ReTry
Message : 
   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
StackTrace:
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.IO.StringWriter.ToString()
   at Ls.WFS.Core.Helper.WebServiceCallHelper.GteFileByte(String physicalFilePath, Int32 bufferSizeInBytesDiv3) in D:\23_Flow\2_Code\Ls.WFS.Core\Helper\WebServiceCallHelper.cs:line 233
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZSuj.png

This is the method for reading a single attachment.If there are multiple attachments, this method will be called in a loop. and this is myCode

```
    private string GteFileByte(string physicalFilePath, int bufferSizeInBytesDiv3 = 1024)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(physicalFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            byte[] data;
            while ((data = reader.ReadBytes(bufferSizeInBytesDiv3)).Length > 0)
            {
                sw.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(data));
            }
            sw.Close();
            reader.Close();
            reader.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**sw.ToString () throws an exception**

I have no idea so far

Ask for help, thank you very much

Comment: How is the memory of the iis process (w3wp.exe) ? Does it happens each time you use this file ? Could you add some debug information including the file size (`new FileInfo(path).Length`)

Comment: The memory usage of the iis process often stays around 1G.
There are three files that are read cyclically, sometimes the first error is reported, and sometimes the third error is reported.It is not possible to determine which file was read and reported the error;

Comment: This is my debug information(new FileInfo(path).Length) {"E: /202003/a9e58d49ec3e4244af12b682c2e4b1e1.pdf":"20633125","E: /202003/b2b00a36a72b46fa8a292fe54be32c28.jpg":"35990"," 202003 / d691fb427b2a4d5cb1d0918befa22698.pdf ":" 32801466 "}

Comment: does it stay around 1Gb even during the crash ? is IIS a 32bit process ? the debug information are the one that happens during a crash ?

Comment: IIS is a 64bit process; memory usage is around 1GB today, there is no exception of memory overflow, maybe they are not using the system today; can you let me know your solution ideas? I can follow this troubleshooting idea to see if it is My code is not written or the server is not configured

Comment: Could you reproduce the exception on a non production environment ? With the information provided I can't see any reason of this exception. Could you get a memory dump when the exception occurs ? See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/using-debugdiag-to-capture-memory-dumps-on-first-chance/ba-p/377131 for more information